# Powershell, Cleaning output data

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to get the Username of any user logged on to any computer. It works fine with 2 Exceptions.

**Here is the code:**

```
$computername = Get-Content 'I:\NodeList\SWSL.txt'
Remove-item "I:\NodeList\UsersPC.txt"
foreach ($computer in $computername) 
{
    if(Test-Connection -Computername $Computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0)
    {        
        $Uinfo = gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $computer | select Username,Caption #,Manufacturer
        $Uinfo | Out-File -Filepath "I:\NodeList\UsersPC.txt" -Append
        Write-Host $Uinfo
    }else{ 
        Write-Host $computer " Is offline, not responing to ping"
        $computer + " Is offline!" | Out-File -Filepath     "I:\NodeList\UsersPC.txt" -Append
    }
}
```

First the Output is:

```
USername       Caption 
--------       ------- 
BINYAN\Charlie SYD-WS04
```

But I would only like to have:

**Charlie SYD-WS04**

The domain is always the same, so I just need the username and the computer name, and NOT the headings or the "---"

2nd Problem is, we are a render farm and all renders are processed on a user account Called "Render".
For those computers I only get the computer name, Username is Blank.
This user account is a Domain user, but not in an OU like the others (Sydney, Melbourne, Brisbane).
It resides in the default "Users" folder in AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the domain name using a `regex` that replaces everything until and including a `\`: `'.*?\\'`

You get rid of the heading using `select -expand` or using a foreach loop where you select the properties using `$_.PROPERTY`

So your statement could look like this:

```
$Uinfo = gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $computer | 
 foreach { '{0} {1}' -f ($_.Username -replace '.*?\\'), $_.Caption }
```

I have no answer for / I dont understand your second question.